# Вывести названия файлов при загрузке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, form

Вот HTML

```
<div class="form--row">
     <div class="input_3">
         <label class="input__label">Файлы</label>
         <input class="input__file" id="attach-contact" type="file" name="attach-contact">
         <label class="input__file-label" for="attach-contact">прикрепить</label>
     </div>              
 </div>

 <div class="files_tags">
     <div class="file_tag">Название файла.дос<button type="button" class="del_tag"></button></div>
     <div class="file_tag">Название файла.дос<button type="button" class="del_tag"></button></div>
     <div class="file_tag">Название файла.дос<button type="button" class="del_tag"></button></div>
 </div>
```

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы в .files_tags выводились названия файлов при их выборе. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант вот так:

```js
// По одному файлу
document.querySelector('#attach-contact').addEventListener("change", (e) => addFile(e.target.files[0].name));

// Несколько файлов
document.querySelector('#attach-contact-multiple').addEventListener("change", (e) => Array.from(e.target.files).forEach(file => addFile(file.name)));


function addFile(fileName) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "file_tag";
  div.innerHTML = fileName;
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className = "del_tag";
  div.append(document.createElement('button'));
  document.querySelector('.files_tags').append(div);
}
```

```html
<div class="form--row">
     <div class="input_3">
         <label class="input__label">Файлы</label>
         <input class="input__file" id="attach-contact" type="file" name="attach-contact">
         <label class="input__file-label" for="attach-contact">прикрепить</label>
     </div>              
 </div>
 

<div class="form--row">
     <div class="input_3">
         <label class="input__label">Несколько файлов</label>
         <input class="input__file"  id="attach-contact-multiple" type="file" name="attach-contact" multiple>
         <label class="input__file-label" for="attach-contact">прикрепить</label>
     </div>              
 </div>
 
  <div class="files_tags"></div>
```

Comment: А при нажатии на .del_tag если через jquery я просто удалю родитель .file_tag - этого будет достаточно, или нужно что то еще сделать?

Comment: Вам еще надо удалить файл из инпута: document.querySelector('#attach-contact').value = ""; С инпутом где крепится несколько файлов, удаляться сразу все.

Comment: А как это сделать правильно? Вписать в value массив с названиями оставшихся файлов? Этого будет достаточно?

Comment: Нативными инструментами удалить один файл из нескольких нельзя. Так как это поле только для чтения. Тут надо смотреть как вы файлы эти будете отправлять на сервер. И пилить свои костыли.

Comment: Я верстаю, бек енд не делаю. Вот умаю как это сделать. Если только верстка то просто удалить .file_tag при нажатии на его дочерний элемент .del_tag. Вот и задался вопросом достаточно ли этого?

Comment: Если только верстка, то достаточно.

Comment: Поставил вам зеленую галочку. Спасибо!!!!